# Is there an easy way to find the derived group of $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, derived-subgroup

In order to find the derived group of $S_5$ I've tried using *Lagrange’s Theorem* to find the order of the possible subgroups but $O(S_5)=2^3\cdot 3 \cdot 5$ so there are too many possible subgroups to look for.

Is there a smarter way to calculate the derived group?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some context explaining why you are asking for methods of finding derived groups of different finite groups (first $Q_8$, not $S_5$)?

Comment: Sure, I recently prooved some useful properties of the derived group for my Algebraic structures class and I was wondering how this properties could be used to determine the derived group of different finite groups but as im new to the concept I was unable to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived subgroup of $S_5$ is normal, and there's only one proper normal subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\geq 5$.

Comment: Is the proof to "there's only one proper normal subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\geq 5$" Easy enough for you to explain here? If not can you tell me somewhere where this is properly explained?

Comment: It's not a one-line proof, but it's basically the same as the corresponding proof that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$. The approach is to show that (1) the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ correspond to cycle lengths, (2) if it contains one of a couple of particular elements, then it must be $A_n$ or $S_n$; (3) any such subgroup contains one of those elements. The proof involves going through a few cases, but it's straightforward; see Hungerford, for example. It's also possible to prove it directly from the fact that $A_n$ is simple, but it's not immediate and still takes a bit of work.

Comment: @anomaly there is a *much* simpler calculation of the derived group $[S_n,S_n]$. Directly check that the commutator $[(123),(345)] = (123)(345)(132)(354)$ is $(143)$, so by replacing $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ with other sets of $5$ numbers we see every $3$-cycle in $S_n$ is a commutator when $n \geq 5$. So $[S_n,S_n]$ contains the subgroup generated by the $3$-cycles, which is $A_n$, so $A_n \subset [S_n,S_n]$. Commutators are all even, so $[S_n,S_n] \subset A_n$. Thus $[S_n,S_n] = A_n$ when $n \geq 5$ (but not when $n < 5$). You don't need to know $A_n$ is simple or all the normal subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: @KCd: That is indeed much better. I've always proved the classification of normal subgroups of $S_n$ en route to or just after proving the normality of $A_n$ (and the commutator computation you mentioned is the first step to the latter). I guess you still need to prove that $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles, but that's usually covered early in an introductory group theory class and easy enough to prove directly otherwise.